# How to type this arrow is MathStack Exchange

Tags: discussion, mathjax

**Problem** I would like to type some extensible right double arrows with texts above it. But I don't know how to do it in MathStack Exchange.I have attached an example in the picture below. I used extarrows.sty package to produce these arrows in Latex.

Btw, I don't know how to tag this question or if I am putting it in the right place...So I just tagged it randomly.

[image]

Comment: \implies will give you $\implies$

Comment: `$\stackrel{U\text{ is open}}\implies$` gives $\stackrel{U\text{ is open}}\implies$.

Comment: @JohnDouma I know this. But how do I make it extensible?

Comment: What's wrong with sentences between your lines

Comment: @user236182 But how do I make it extensible though? I think it looks nicer if extensible..

Comment: `\xrightarrow{\because U\text{ is open}}` gives $\xrightarrow{\because U\text{ is open}}$ but you might do better to ask this at tex.stackexchange and mention MathJax

Comment: @Henry last time I checked MJ was off-topic there. // Indeed it still is... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276872/how-to-type-this-arrow-is-mathstack-exchange

Comment: @quid Looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=MathJax and  http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-do-we-feel-about-mathjax-jsmath-other-spin-offs it seems that sometimes they are helpful and sometimes not: TeX syntax questions (which this really is) are supposed to be on-topic there while MathJaX installation questions are not.

Comment: Some older posts, which might be useful (or at least related): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11912/how-to-typeset-those-symbols-using-mathjax and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11900/text-and-mathjax-above-symbol (The first one would definitely deserve a more descriptive title, which would improve searching and many other things. If somebody has an idea for the good title, please, do edit it. EDIT: In fact, I have edited the tile now - using a phrase from the body of post - but still there is probably some space for improvements.)

Comment: @Henry the point is a bit moot now and had I not thought in error that the exchange in which I participated was extremely recent I would have said something more elaborate. Still I continue to think that as a rule it is not  a good idea to send MJ questions there. (The syntax is not identical either. Especially, not everything that works in (La)TeX will work in MJ.)