# How to draw extensible vertical arrows?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

In [How to type this arrow is MathStack Exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21880/290189) and its duplicate target, a few ways are provided to typeset a horizontal extensible arrow.

$$\Large\rlap{\color{blue}{\underset{(0,0)}{\times}}}{\;\;\:\xrightarrow[\bf i]{\hspace{5em}}{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\color{blue}{\underset{(1,0)}{\times}}}}$$

How can we typeset vertical arrows?

In [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), there's no guidance on extensible horizontal arrow `\xrightarrow`, but the section **Markov Chains** included a commutative diagram that makes use of this command.

The command

```
\raise{34px}{\vert}\hspace{-5px}\raise{17px}{\vert}\hspace{-12.2px}\downarrow
```

suggested in

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30293/290189

looks bad.

$$\raise{34px}{\vert}\hspace{-5px}\raise{17px}{\vert}\hspace{-12.2px}\downarrow$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
\begin{array}{l}
\color{blue}{\times\, (0,1)}\\[-4pt]
\kern1px \left\uparrow\vcenter{\rule{0pt}{7em}}\rlap{\,\mathbf{j}}\right.\\[-4pt]
\color{blue}{\times\, (0,0)}
\end{array}
```

which gives

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\color{blue}{\times\, (0,1)}\\[-4pt]
\kern1px \left\uparrow\vcenter{\rule{0pt}{7em}}\rlap{\,\mathbf{j}}\right.\\[-4pt]
\color{blue}{\times\, (0,0)}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: thanks.  your answer deserves more upvotes than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I resort to the crappy solution, with a few tweaks.

$$\raise{45pt}{\rlap{\raise{8pt}{\color{blue}{\times (1,0)}}}{\Large\wedge}} \hspace{-20pt} \begin{array}{c|c} &\\\\[1.5em] \phantom{\bf j}&{\bf j} \\\\[1.5em]&\end{array} \hspace{-18pt}
\raise{-50pt}{\color{blue}{\times (0,0)}}$$

- I got the values `45pt`, `-20pt`, etc by trial and error.
- Despite the possibility of changing vertical space by `\\[...]`, as revealed in [Does MathJaX have a command to stretch or reduce vertical space?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13649/290189), that doesn't work with negative dimensions.
- As a result, I have to put them "on the same line", then use `\raise{dim}{...}` and `\hspace{...}` to control the spacing.
- I'm using the middle line separating a "two-column array" as the arrow body.  The two `\\[...]` controls the height of the arrow.  The ampersands `&` near the start and the end of the `array` environment keep the position of the arrow label in the middle.
- In the middle of the `array` environment, we have `\phantom{...} & ...`, so that on the left, we reserve the same horizontal spacing as on the right without displaying the content.